# Why don't boundary layers have a transverse pressure gradient due to the Bernoulli effect?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, bernoulli-equation

This is something I always thought about but never truly understood.
A boundary layer has a velocity gradient, $\partial u/ \partial y$. The Bernoulli principle states that pressure and velocity are inversely related. Ignoring gravity, why doesn't that result in a pressure gradient, $-\partial p/\partial y$, causing the fluid to curve upward to the lower pressure region?

Comment: Bernoulli effect doesn't apply to viscous flows.

Comment: Bernoulli applies along a streamline.